# Executing a stored procedure with a table variable via pdo

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, pdo

I have a stored procedure with two seperate select statements. The results are saved in a table variable. In the end of the SP the table variable is outputted.

So, if I execute the SP on the server itself (via MS SQL Server Management Studio) the reslut is like expected. But when I try to call the SP in PHP it doesn't work anymore.

Here is my PHP code:

```
$querySelectRemindersToBeExecuted = $this->dbConnectionWAM->prepare("{call spGetRemindersToBeExecuted}");

if($querySelectRemindersToBeExecuted->execute(array()))
{                
    var_dump($querySelectRemindersToBeExecuted->fetch()); // returns false
    while($row = $querySelectRemindersToBeExecuted->fetch())
    {
        echo "fetching";
    }
    var_dump($querySelectRemindersToBeExecuted->errorInfo()); // returns error message below
}
else
     var_dump($querySelectRemindersToBeExecuted->errorInfo()); // no error
```

Error message from the second var_dump:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string 'IMSSP' (length=5)
  1 => int -15
  2 => string 'The active result for the query contains no fields.' (length=51)
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Did you ever found a solution to your problem? I'm facing similar issues with a declared table I want to reference in a query. A query like `declare @mytable table(id int, name varchar(255)) insert into @table values (1, 'test') select * from @table` results in the same error.

Comment: @Ben nope, unfortunately not... I solved my problem without using the SP and the table variable...

Comment: Thanks for replying on the old comment I left. I've abandonded the case since stored procedures were not an option.